# How to help users avoid making conscious mistakes?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, errors, error-prevention

I am working on the navigation pattern and design of a mobile application. I am facing a problem.

The user has to choose one item from a list of items.
[image]

Best scenario: The user chooses the correct item and a machine launches.

Bad scenario: The user clicks on an item, launches a machine but figures out that he chose the wrong item. The chosen item will be launched two hours after selecting.

Question: How do I make sure that user chooses the right item?

Comment: Why do you want to offer options that you know the user does not want to choose? Can you add some more context or share some wireframes etc. to understand the situation better?

Comment: This list is a list of activities of the day. So i need to display multiple choices. The list will be updated every day. Every choice is related with a machine, a place and a user.

Comment: Kindly provide either wireframes or screenshots or some relevant reference because the question us quite unclear at the moment

Comment: How does the user knows which item is the best choice? Does your system know which item is the possible best choice?

Comment: @locationunknown that's what i am looking for. how does user will know the best choice.

Comment: @Hamdy someone knows the best/correct choice, someone makes the choice. What is the best/correct choice based on? The one making the choice needs to know something they can base their choice on.

Comment: @Shreyas Tripathy i add a picture to explain the pattern

Comment: This is simply about helping users avoid mistakes. The Nielsen Norman Group have produced a lot of work on the topic. See my answer for link and suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Do users want to do things that you don't want them to do? How does the user know they made a wrong choice? Do they simply change their mind and need a "start over"? I'd suggest you just let users make their own choices, as long as the system can support those choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Help avoid conscious mistakes by 'Previewing Results', 'Warning Before Errors are Made', and 'Supporting Undo'

**Previewing Results, Warning Before Errors are Made**

From the [NNG article *Preventing User Errors: Avoiding Conscious Mistakes*:](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/user-mistakes/)

> Sometimes, users don’t realize they’re about to trigger an action that results in changes that are wide in scope and difficult to verify. Users may well wish to revise their goals once they have had a chance to compare the effect of the action with their goal; Preview features provide an opportunity to bridge the Gulf of Evaluation without making a mistake.

In your case, you might do this by **turning your final screen into a review screen with a more specific/detailed CTA**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT0OIr.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Supporting 'Undo'**

> Another primary principle of preventing users from making errors is to acknowledge that they will make mistakes and slips from time to time, and provide a safety net that makes these errors less costly

This is obviously more subject to technical restrictions, but a standard heuristic evaluation point of a system like this is "Can key actions be undone?".
If it's technically possible to support this function, you should consider it.

Comment: you have pointed to a good point about cancel key action. the machine will return some data. i can work with data at rest but this we obliged to check the data incoming from the machine before sending it to the server. this is a hard work to do. so the support undo that you have mentioned is a good idea. even i can use the undo time to check the conncetivity of the device.